# What do these red crosses mean

Tags: pcb, altium, trace, circuitmaker

I'm using CircuitMaker (Altium 'Free') and I get on a lot of components/traces red crosses, but sometimes only part of a trace (see screenshot).

What do these crosses mean?

[image]

Note, I haven't connected everything yet, but these are annoying as when I'm zooming out I cannot see what traces are on the front and bottom layer as they all show in red. See screenshot below.

The first picture show the C7 and C9 capacitors.

[image]

Comment: Does this post answer your question or help in any way: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341075/altium-designer-how-to-remove-green-xs-error-markers

Comment: How small are your traces?

Comment: @EdinFifić Thanks, yes that seems to be the problem, to solve it though is not successful yet.

Comment: @RonBeyer 5 mils ... a bit minimal, but it's just a try ... I see two traces show < 5 mil, but i'ts just the continuation of a trace (the blue and the error-blue horizontal lines). Also selecting something in CircuitMaker is really troublesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They indicate a "violation" of some kind.

I don't know Circuitmaker, but in Altium, you can right-click on the object and one of the options in the pop-up menu will be "Violations..." which will tell you why there is a violation.

In this case, it's possible you didn't assign the tracks to the GND net, so you have copper assigned to the GND net (the 3 pads) touching copper assigned to "No Net", which is treated as an undesired short circuit. This could happen if you used "Place Line" instead of "Place Track" or "Interactive routing" to add the tracks.

Comment: Thanks; going to look into it.

Comment: The problem was, it was not connected to the GND net indeed. When I routed it, and pressed Reset Error Markers (comment of Edin Fific above), the crosses are gone.